# Playing exotic WAV files with Java

Tags: java, javasound, javax.sound.sampled

I have a WAV file encoded with ADPCM (id=2), mono, 4 bits per sample and a "fact" chunk. Much stuff that does not appear in "normal" wavs.

The AudioFileReader class of AudioInputStream already fails when parsing the format code (here 2 == ADPCM), it only accepts 1,3,6 and 7.

Is there another way to play such files? Since standard Java obviously cannot do that.

This is the file: https://anonfile.com/c1ianfj5b5/music_wav

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your question a little. You can't see it, but somebody voted to close the question as "asking for off-site resource". I hope that, by editing the question a little, it will stay open.

Comment: Are you looking for a pure Java solution? If not, which OS? Also, can you please post a link to a sample file?

Comment: A pure java solution would be best but is not a requirement.
I use windows.

Comment: My browser (Firefox) also can't play it. But Audacity and Reaper does.

Comment: @paul Did my answer solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

For Windows(32/64) and macOS(64) you can use [FFSampledSP](http://www.tagtraum.com/ffsampledsp/), v0.9.29 or later. You can get it either via this Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.tagtraum</groupId>
    <artifactId>ffsampledsp-complete</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.29</version>
</dependency>
```

Or via this download [link](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/tagtraum/ffsampledsp-complete/0.9.29/ffsampledsp-complete-0.9.29.jar).

Once the `.jar` is in the classpath, the following code *should* work:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PlayADPCM {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException {
        final File file = new File("your_adpcm_file.wav");
        final AudioInputStream stream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        final AudioFormat format = stream.getFormat();
        System.out.println("Source format: " + format);
        final AudioFormat targetFormat = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
            format.getSampleRate(), 16, format.getChannels(),
            format.getChannels()*2,
            format.getSampleRate(), format.isBigEndian());
        System.out.println("Target format: " + targetFormat);
        // convert source to target format
        final AudioInputStream playableStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(targetFormat, stream);
        // get a line and play it.
        final DataLine.Info lineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, targetFormat);
        final SourceDataLine line = (SourceDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(lineInfo);
        line.open(targetFormat);
        line.start();
        final byte[] buf = new byte[1024*8];
        int justRead;
        while ((justRead = playableStream.read(buf))>0) {
            line.write(buf, 0, justRead);
        }
        playableStream.close();
        line.drain();
        line.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try it.

Comment: Hey @paul—how did this work out? Please accepts the answer, if it worked for you.

Comment: for me this worked. on linux manjaro. but it logs sometimes "Invalid return value 0 for stream protocol"

Comment: @neoexpert If you can reliably reproduce the behavior with a specific audio file, please file an issue at https://github.com/hendriks73/ffsampledsp/issues